# RequestRateLimited in CKQueryOperation

Tags: ios, cloudkit

If a `CKQueryOperation` returns a `RequestRateLimited` error, should the same queryOperation added to publicDatabase, or should a new queryOperation created based on the cursor received? Does client receive cursor if `RequestRateLimited` error occurred?

---

@farktronix:

- you shouldn't receive a new query cursor
- you can retry the same operation again

am I implemented it well, because I get an error (in simulator, under poor  internet condition)

> -[NSOperationQueue addOperation:]: operation is finished and cannot be enqueued

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), {

    // ..other things

    let qo = CKQueryOperation(query: query)
    let qcb: (CKQueryCursor!, NSError!) -> () = {cursor, error in

        if error == nil {

            //.. some code

        } else {

            if error.code == CKErrorCode.RequestRateLimited.rawValue {

                let retryAfter = error.userInfo![CKErrorRetryAfterKey] as! NSNumber

                dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(retryAfter.doubleValue * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))), dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), {

                    publicDatabase.addOperation(qo) // <- HERE is it ok? I get an error
                })
            } else {

                // .. some other code
            }
        }
    }

    qo.queryCompletionBlock = qcb
    publicDatabase.addOperation(qo)

    // .. other things ..
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you receive a `CKErrorRequestRateLimited` error then you shouldn't receive a new query cursor.

Any time you receive a rate limited error you can retry the same operation again after the time specified in the userInfo dictionary under the `CKErrorRetryAfterKey` key has elapsed.

Comment: I get an error when got `RequestRateLimited` error response, I added relevant code into question, you said that I do not have to create new query, but now I am confused

Comment: Since a `NSOperation` can only be run once you'll need to create a new instance of the operation with all of the same properties. You can use the same `CKQuery` on the new operation.